# How to use scram-sha-256 in Postgres 10 in Debian? Getting "FATAL: password authentication failed"

Tags: postgresql, authentication, postgresql-10, sasl-scram

I edited `pg_hba.conf`:

```
sudo su postgres
nano /etc/postgresql/10/main/pg_hba.conf
```

and added this line:

```
local   all             username                               scram-sha-256
```

and changed all `md5` to `scram-sha-256` in that file.

As the `postgres` user, I created a new user with superuser rights:

```
sudo su postgres
psql

CREATE USER username WITH SUPERUSER PASSWORD 'password';
```

Then I restarted Postgres:

```
/etc/init.d/postgresql restart
```

and tried to login with pgAdmin4 where I changed the username under the database's Connection properties. But neither that nor `psql -U username testdb < ./testdb.sql` work as I'm getting:

> FATAL: password authentication failed for user "username"

So how can I get Postgres working with scram-sha-256 on my Debian9/KDE machine? It worked earlier when I left all the `md5` in `pg_hba.conf` as they were.

Comment: Or if the logging has been configured, you will see in the log: `DETAIL:  User "foouser" does not have a valid SCRAM verifier.` Indeed, it makes sense that PostgreSQL should be configured to actually store those hashes in the correct format.

Comment: Easy step-by-step [tutorial](https://blog.crunchydata.com/blog/how-to-upgrade-postgresql-passwords-to-scram) how to upgrade from `md5` to `scram-sha-256`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[The fine manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-password.html) says:

> To upgrade an existing installation from `md5` to `scram-sha-256`, after having ensured that all client libraries in use are new enough to support SCRAM, set `password_encryption = 'scram-sha-256'` in `postgresql.conf`, make all users set new passwords, and change the authentication method specifications in `pg_hba.conf` to `scram-sha-256`.

Comment: Another issue as I recall is that the user must be using a connection library/driver that has added support for the [SCRAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salted_Challenge_Response_Authentication_Mechanism) protocol. Perhaps the OP’s *psql* supported SCRAM but not their *pgAdmin*?

Comment: It worked after setting 'scram-sha-256' in postgresql.conf, restarting postgresql and then ALTERing the user. I didn't set it in that config file as it wasn't really an "upgrade" from MD5 to SCRAM but a new installation and the password_encryption line was commented out. I also got that same error when ALTERing the user before restarting postgresql. It's pretty clear indeed; but maybe it would be a good idea to move that up to the "scram-sha-256" section as that's  where I'd expect any info on that encryption method to be located.

Answer (score 4):

Also check current password hash format:

```
postgres=# select passwd from pg_shadow where usename='username';
passwd
--------------
md5...

postgres=# set password_encryption = 'scram-sha-256';
SET
postgres=# alter user username with password 'secretpass';
ALTER ROLE
postgres=# select passwd from pg_shadow where usename='username';
passwd
--------------------------
SCRAM-SHA-256$...
(1 row)
```